# Asp net core query string params serialization

Tags: json, rest, serialization, asp.net-core, http-get

Can I use complex types as query string params for the HttpGet request in Asp.NET Core MVC app?

I had a problem with it, when i try to pass the param as complex type, like this:

```
[Route("reportData")]
[HttpGet]
public List<dynamic> GetReportData(int reportId, int scope [FromQuery] ReportFilterMetadataDto filters)
{
    ...                
}
```

all of properties in filters objects have null value. But if I pass filters like string and deserialize it into destination type, like this:

```
[Route("reportData")]
[HttpGet]
public List<dynamic> GetReportData(int reportId, int, string filters)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportFilterMetadataDto>(filters);
}
```

there are no problems. Is it necessary to implement custom serializer or configure asp net core app MVC, or use middleware to getting correct result. Maybe I done anything in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably null due to a binding failure.
Try the following:

```
   [HttpGet("reportData/{reportId}/{scope}")]
   public List<dynamic> GetReportData(int reportId, int scope [FromQuery] 
       ReportFilterMetadataDto filters)
   {
      ...                
   }
```

You can also have multiple FromQuery attributes. However, with the amount of information you are getting, maybe consider this method as Post and send get the dto FromBody.